# Ruby on rails chapter 5 tutorials fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

i'm working on tutorial in chapter 5 and i get this error.
i already try to fix it by referring to other question but still can't find the problem

here is my failure

```
syahmies-MacBook-Air:sample_app syahmie$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
.F.F.FF..

Failures:

  1) Static pages Contact page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('Contact')) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x007fe5f9609168>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Help page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fe5f92bf7c8>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages About page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('About Us')) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3:0x007fe5fc83b2d0>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Static pages Home page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('')) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fe5fc90b138>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.30171 seconds
9 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33 # Static pages Contact page
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19 # Static pages Help page
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26 # Static pages About page
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11 # Static pages Home page

Randomized with seed 35702
```

and this is my spec.rb file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_content('Sample App') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('')) }
    it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    it { should have_content('Help') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }

    it { should have_content('About') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('About Us')) }
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    it { should have_content('Contact') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Contact')) }
  end

end
```

Comment: add the code to the question, so it still makes sense after the pastebins get removed.

Comment: @sevenseacat actually i don't know how to add code to the question.i still a newbie in this forum

Comment: compare the code in your specs to the code in the tutorial. Yours is very different.

Comment: thanks for the edit.yes it little different bcoz i am using tutorial given by my mentor but it still use the same code

Comment: where have you defined the `full_title` method?

Comment: so... where have you defined the `full_title` method?

Comment: thanks for your help.i know where i was wrong.i put the support folder in request folder instead of spec folder